# Group people by job type in Excel column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following transformation to do:

a list of items on that are working some types of people (jurists, avocates etc.)

I have item id, person type, and person id.

I need to dispatch avocats and juristes (actually I have 5 such types, in the real project), to have columns item id, avocats, jurists and coma separated ids in these columns.

[image]

Is that possible via Excel tools, or should I write a custom macro for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try a combination of cascaded IF and TEXTJOIN functions. For `avocats`, use the following formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(F2=$A$2:$A$9,IF($B$2:$B$9="avocat",$C$2:$C$9,""),""))
```

[image]

The same formula applies for `juristes`, except the criteria is changed to suit the word `juriste`

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(F2=$A$2:$A$9,IF($B$2:$B$9="juriste",$C$2:$C$9,""),""))
```

[image]

Adapt the formula to the other criteria.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FILTER` + `TEXTJOIN`

I chose to make the source data into a TABLE and use structured references, so you can easily add rows to the table without changing references, but you could use regular addressing/references if you prefer:

```
=IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(",",,FILTER(PTypes[[PERSON ID]:[PERSON ID]],(PTypes[[ITEM ID]:[ITEM ID]]=$E2)*(PTypes[[P.TYPE]:[P.TYPE]]=F$1))),"")
```

and fill down and across as needed.

[image]